# In Excel how can I share a spreadsheet attachment in Gmail? by default it opens up Outlook

Tags: excel, email, gmail, spreadsheet

Whilst open in Excel how can I send the file as an attachment in Gmail?

In Excel, File > Share > Email by default opens up Outlook

how can I change this to open up and attach by default in Gmail

Comment: You probably want to post this at https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use Outlook as your GMail client. There is no way to change Excel to share to a web email account.